# Capacitance changes by a factor of 3 or 9?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

This is an example problem with solution in a book I am reading on electrostatics.

"We have two square parallel plate capacitors with length $a$ and separation $d$ with $d<<a$.  If we triple all dimensions of the capacitor, by what factor does the capacitance change?"

$C=\frac{\epsilon_0A}{d}$ and $A$ is the area.  The book says the capacitance would change by a factor of $3$, but doesn't it change by a factor of $9$?

$C=\frac{\epsilon_0(a)^2}{d}\longrightarrow\frac{\epsilon_0(3a)^2}{d}= 9\frac{\epsilon_0(a^2)}{d}$

Comment: Hint: What's that $d$ in the denominator?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: $d$ is the distance between them...?  OK, tripling all dimensions also implies the thickness?  So the distance between the plates would decrease by a factor of 3?

Comment: Why should the distance decrease if you triple ALL coordinates? And how would that get you a factor of 9? You are pretty close, you just have to plug in the right numbers!

Comment: Tripling all dimensions.. does $d$ become $3d$?  If so, then $C=\frac{\epsilon_0(3a)^2}{3d}=\frac{9\epsilon_0(a)^2}{3d}$ for a factor of $3$?